# How do I find a matching sentence in another column and copy the value in the adjance cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column of sentences(C2~C30), some are duplicates.
If there is a matching sentence in the column D(D2~D10), I want to copy the value from the same row in the Column E and paste it the same row in the column B.

For example, C14 matches with D6, so I want to copy the value from E6 and paste it in B6.

I tried index and match function but it's not working.
I would appreciate help.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Formula in `B2:` `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C30,D2:E10,2,0),"Not found")`

Answer (score 0):

The applied formula:

Convert to uppercase the text  (drag down)

`=IFERROR(INDEX(E$55:E$59,MATCH(UPPER(C55),UPPER(D$55:D$59),0)),"")`

[image]

Comment: Using `UPPER` is redundant because `MATCH` is already case-insensitive i.e. e.g. `s = S`. Also, the result could spill by using `C55:C66` instead of `C55`.